# How to detect whether XML elements have child elements

Tags: perl, libxml2

I am using the CPAN [`XML::LibXML`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) module to process the XML data below. I need to to determine whether each element has a child element or not. Searching around I can't find any example for that purpose.

```
<A>
    <ts>2012</ts>
    <T>M1</T>
    <T>M2</T>
    <B>
        <id>PC</id>
        <r>10</r>
        <r>30</r>
    </B>
</A>
```

This is the Perl code I havae written

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my ($x,$elname,$haschild)= ();
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $npo    = $parser->parse_file("test.xml");
my $rootel = $npo -> getDocumentElement();
$elname = $rootel -> nodeName();
print "Root name=$elname\n";

foreach $x ($rootel->childNodes) {
    $elname = $x -> nodeName();
    $haschild = $x->hasChildNodes;
    print "Child name = $elname and has child = $haschild.\n" unless ($elname =~ /#text/i);
}
```

While I used `childNodes` to go through each node, I just can't find an easy way to determine whether the node has a child or not.

I am expecting to get result after looping through all the nodes that:

```
A: Has children
ts: Has none
T: has none
T: has none
B: Has children
id: Has none
r: Has none
r: Has none
```

The result I am getting is like this:

```
Root name=A
Child name = ts and has child = 1.
Child name = T and has child = 1.
Child name = T and has child = 1.
Child name = B and has child = 1.
```

It seems all nodes return true after the `hasChildNodes` condition check.

Comment: Well, you've got sample data, but how about posting the code you've got, even though it doesn't work yet?

Comment: You are mistaken. All of those nodes have (text) child nodes, just like libxml is telling. You apparently mistakenly think "node" and "element" means the same thing, but that's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is the number of child *elements* of a node. The child *nodes* would include text and insignificant whitespace.

The easiest way to count the number of child elements a node has is to use `findnodes('*')->size` as the XPath expression `*` counts only child elements.

Here is some code that does what you describe

```perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<XML);
<A>
    <ts>2012</ts>
    <T>M1</T>
    <T>M2</T>
    <B>
        <id>PC</id>
        <r>10</r>
        <r>30</r>
    </B>
</A>
XML

my $nodes = $xml->findnodes('//*');
foreach my $node ($nodes->get_nodelist) {
  my $children;
  for ($node->findnodes('*')->size) {
    $children = 'none' when 0;
    $children = '1 child' when 1;
    default { $children = "$_ children" }
  }
  printf "%s: has %s\n", $node->localname, $children;
}
```

**output**

```
A: has 4 children
ts: has none
T: has none
T: has none
B: has 3 children
id: has none
r: has none
r: has none
```

Answer (score 3):

What about the `hasChildNodes` method?

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $xml = XML::LibXML->createDocument;
$xml->setDocumentElement($xml->createElement('root'));
$xml->documentElement->addChild($xml->createElement('son'));
for my $node ($xml->documentElement,
              $xml->documentElement->firstChild) {
    print $node->hasChildNodes, "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1
0
```

Keep in mind that a text node is a child node, too (i.e. node and element are different notions).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know if a child node exists then the test:

`$node->exists('*')`

would be more efficient than:

`$node->findnodes('*')->size`

because it would exit as soon as the first node had been found.