# Using XML::libXML to parse xml--get nth Child Node

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

I have an xml document that contains information I want to put into a database. Example:

```
<pc>
    <name>John</name>
    <last>Smith</last>
    <address>
        <business>
            <street>987 Broad Way</street>
            <city>New York</city>
            <state>New York</state>
        </business>
        <home>
            <street>123 Main St.</street>
            <city>Jersey City</city>
            <state>Nebraska</state>
        </home>
    </address>
    <phone>123-456-7890</phone>
</pc>
```

I am planing on using perl to parse this data to build mysql statements. I am having problems getting a format like the following:

```
name="John"
last="Smith"
...
```

The code I am using so far is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "sample.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file($filename);

for my $contact ($xmldoc->findnodes('/server')){
    print $contact->nodeName(),"\n";
    foreach my $child ($contact->findnodes('*')){
        print "\t", $child->nodeName(), ":\n";
        foreach my $grandchild ($child->findnodes('*')){
            print"\t\t", $grandchild->nodeName(), ":", $grandchild->textContent(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't use perl much, and I am not overly familiar with the XML::libXML library ([http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML)). I guess I need to find the last child and work my way back up the node? I am kind of lost as to how I should go about constructing my "inserts" and "updates" for mysql.

Comment: Your code has no relation to your input and to your stated desired output, which isn't SQL despite stating you wanted SQL. And your title indicates a desire to find the n-th child, which is completely unnecessary for the given XML. Could you make some sense of this all?

Comment: Sorry, my thought was that I would use perl to parse the xml file and build sql statements and run them all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790057/with-perl-libxml-how-to-detect-nodes-with-or-without-child) to go through all the children. Here is my finished code:

```
my $nodes = $xml->findnodes('//*');
foreach my $node ($nodes->get_nodelist) {
  my $children;
  my $nodeSide = ($node->findnodes('*')->size);
if ($nodeSize > 0){
printf "%n%s :\n", $node->localname;
}
else {
printf "%s: %s\n", $node->localname, $node->textContent();
}
}
```

With the output, I could do something like,

insert into db ($node->textContent());

again, that's not a good sql statement, but I will work on that later. The important part was the node separation and iteration.